# $x^2-3x-10<0$ and $ |x-2|<a$ sufficient and necessary condition for a

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

We have that

$$x^2-3x-10<0 \implies -2<x<5$$

while

$$ |x-2|<a\implies x-2<a \quad \lor \quad2-x<a$$

Edit:

> > What is the range value of $a$ such that $ |x-2|<a$  is a necessary condition for $x^2-3x-10<0$
> >     What is the range value of $a$ such that $ |x-2|<a$  is a sufficient condition for $x^2-3x-10<0$

I input the $x = -2$ and $x = 5$ into $x-2<a$ and $2-x<a$ 
Resulting :$ -4<a, -3<a, 3<a, 4<a$

I kinda having trouble deciding which is the sufficient or necessary condition for a

1. Sufficient condition: I think it is $a>4$
2. Necessary condition: I think it is $a>3$

Is it right?

Comment: Necessity and sufficiency can be confusing. See if the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) helps and try to set up the implications very carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$x^2-3x-10<0 \iff (x-5)(x+2)<0 \iff -2< x<5$$

and assuming $a>0$

$$|x-2|<a \iff -a< x-2 < a\iff -a+2< x < a+2$$

and the second inequality is compatible with the first one for $a\le a_{max}=3$.

Comment: I have edited some in the question

Comment: I think that $a\le 3$ is necessary and $a\le 2$ is sufficient. Maybe $a<4$ is wrong since $x<6$ is not compatible with $x<5$.

Comment: I forgot to mention there is actually options to choose. The answer is for sufficient is $0< a\leq 3$ and necessary was $a\geq 4$. Perhaps you can edited your answer.

Comment: Based on your $-a+2<x<a+2$ and comment, it makes sense that the sufficient is the options $0< a \leq 3$ because all $a$ satisfy the $ x^2-3x-10$ aka sufficient. And for $a\geq 4$ it is necessary include yes and no of $x$ satisfying the equation.